# Disable form submit while file is loading FilePond

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, filepond

I am using [FilePond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/) for image file in my form. I want form submit to be `disabled` while image/file is loading. and reenabled once image is loaded.

I searched their docs but couldn't find what might help

This  when `Submit` button should be disabled

[image]

Comment: There are plenty of callbacks i can see on their official docs. It would be helpful if you can add a working example of the code you have in place and what do you mean by file is loading exactly?

Comment: when we drag and drop an image it takes some tile to load the image and then it is ready to be encode and send. so i want that submit to be disabled while it is loading the uploaded image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using these callbacks, you can disable the submit button while the files load.

`onaddfilestart(file)` – Started file load

`onaddfileprogress(file, progress)` Made progress loading a file

`onaddfile(error, file)`    If no error, file has been successfully loaded.

```
function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FilePond
        files={files}
        allowReorder={true}
        allowMultiple={true}
        onupdatefiles={setFiles}
        onaddfilestart={()=> setLoading(true)}
        onaddfile={()=> setLoading(false)}
      />
      <button disabled={loading}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

reference - https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/properties/#callbacks

Comment: thnx it worked. i actually saw those callback on docs but they didnt work. this didnt came in my mind. thnx again